# How to push to GitHub after changing the repository name in GitHub

Tags: git, github, repository

My repository was Porfolio3, and I changed it to Portfolio (without the 3) on GitHub. I'm still working on it, and I don't want to lose it. I went into my local code and typed "git push" as usual but I got this:

```
D:\GitHub\01 Portfolio> git push
To https://github.com/moki929/Portfolio
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/moki929/Portfolio'   
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do    
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes   
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I've tried many things like:

> PS D:\GitHub\01 Portfolio> git remote add origin-push $(git config https://github.com/moki929/Portfolio.git)

but I get this

> error: invalid key: https://github.com/moki929/Portfolio.git

My git status:

```
PS D:\GitHub\01 Portfolio> git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'destination/master' by 3 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

I tried to rename origin to destination. Thinking that would fix it. Do I need to change back to origin? I just want to push to GitHub.

Comment: What about `git remote --set-url origin <url>`?

Comment: The error message told you to sync the remote first. You could try `git fetch --all` first, then `git rebase origin/master` or  `git merge origin/master`. Then you can try to  `git push` again.

Comment: PS D:\GitHub\01 Portfolio> git fetch --all
Fetching destination
From https://github.com/moki929/Portfolio
Fetching origin-push
...Portfolio> git rebase origin/master
fatal: invalid upstream 'origin/master'
...Portfolio> git merge origin/master
merge: origin/master - not something we can merge
...Portfolio> git push
To https://github.com/moki929/Portfolio
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
...
...Portfolio> git remote --set-url origin https://github.com/moki929/Portfolio.git
error: unknown option `set-url'

Comment: It worked! I had to change it back with: git remote rename destination origin
...
all those errors above didn't happen again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are in "origin", fetch, rebase, merge, and push. As below:

```
git remote rename destination origin
git fetch --all
git rebase origin/master
git merge origin/master
git push
```

Thanks Chuck Lu!
https://stackoverflow.com/users/13338936/chuck-lu